# Java - Create a 2 dimensional array that can be manipulated and printed by other methods

Tags: java, arrays, variable-length

I am trying to create a 2-dimensional array without using ArrayList. I was successful at creating the array but I run into a snag when trying to print the array from another method because the array is not static. However, I cannot make the array static because I am also allowing the user to decided the size of the array. I thought I could override the array and then print it but that only returns null values. Should this be done with a variable-length argument?

```
public class Array {
public static int[][] array1;     


    public static void makeArray(){

      int [][] array1 = new int [Menu.arrayRow][Menu.arrayCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < array1[0].length; j++) {
                  array1[i][j] = (i * array1[0].length) + j + 1;
             }
        }   
    }// end of makeArray


    public  static void displayArray(){

                for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < array1[0].length; j++) {
                  array1[i][j] = (i * array1[0].length) + j + 1;
                  System.out.print(array1[i][j] + ", ");
             }
             System.out.println("");
        }

    }// end of displayArray
```

This is the result of running the program and choosing item #11 from my menu to display the array:

```
run:
Enter the number of rows for the array:5
Enter the number of columns for the array:5
========================================



    1. Insert a Row
    2. Insert a Column 
    3. Swap rows
    4. Swap columns
    5. Swap Upper and Lower triangles
    6. Display the triangles
    7. Reverse the contents of a column
    8. Reverse the diagnal
    9. Swap diagnals
    10. Display a subsection of the current 2D array
    11. Display the array
    12. Exit
    Choose an option from the menu :
11
========================================
```

[image]

Comment: Pass the array itself to the method manipulating the array

Comment: Please read through [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). (don't want to close for duplicate though, still specific enough in my opinion)

Comment: Passing the array to the method a likely getting me closer to resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring the array again in the create method scope:

```
int [][] array1 = ...
```

Just remove that:

```
array1 = ...
```

To access the class level array.

When you declare a local variable, you will access that in the `makeArray` method, and not the static field. Then, the field is still null when you call the next method. Beware not to 'shade' class variables with local variables.

Comment: Isn't the class level array null by this definition? I feel like you're on to something, but I may be missing the point.

Comment: The class level array is null because it's never set; the `makeArray` method I assume you are calling is actually declaring a new local variable and assigning a new array to that, leaving the class level array null. That's why you get a null pointer on `displayArray`. Either change it as I proposed, so that `makeArray` and `displayArray` access the same array (class level), or, as per suggested by Elliott, make every method take or return the array, and hold its reference on the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Return the array from `makeArray` and pass the array to `displayArray`. I would also pass the `row` and `col` counts as arguments to the create. Like,

```
public class Array {
    public static int[][] makeArray(int row, int col) {
        int[][] array1 = new int[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
                array1[i][j] = (i * array1[i].length) + j + 1;
            }
        }
        return array1;
    }// end of makeArray

    public static void displayArray(int[][] array1) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array1));
    }
}
```

Comment: passing the area seems like the right move to the indexes to be printed, but deeptoString isn't working. I think a for loop would still work within the displayArray method once the array is passed, but is there another way to call that method to print?

Comment: @Elbowgrease `deepToString` was just an example (it's built-in). **how** are you calling it? you didn't post that code. Save the array returned in `makeArray`, pass **that array** to `displayArray`.

Comment: Array.displayArray(int [ ][ ] array 1);          I have not tried printing with a passed array in this manner before

Comment: `Array.displayArray(array1);` assuming one of the previous lines is something like `int[][] array1 = Array.makeArray(5, 3);` it is the same as passing any other kind of variable to a method.